# is there any difference between these two ways of outputing html content with php performance wise?

Tags: php, performance

```
<?php
            foreach($pricelistline as $value) {
                $e = explode(",",$value);
                if ($e[0]) {
                    echo "<li>\n<img width=\"24\" height=\"24\" src=\"features_icons/" . $e[0] . ".png\" alt=\"\" class=\"\" />\n<span>" . str_replace("-", " ", ucfirst($e[0])) . "</span>\n</li>\n";
                }
            }
?>
```

And this_

```
<?php
            foreach($pricelistline as $value) {
                $e = explode(",",$value);
                if ($e[0]) {
?>
                    <li>
                        <img width="24" height="24" src="features_icons<?php echo $e[0]; ?>.png" alt="" class="" />
                        <span><?php echo str_replace("-", " ", ucfirst($e[0])); ?></span>
                    </li>
<?php
                }
            }
?>
```

In general is there any difference performance wise?
Is there any difference in speed and load?

Does exiting and entering php multiple times degrade performance? `<?php >`

Which one is considered a better practice?

Is there any difference between 1 instance of echo vs 2 instances?

Comment: Go for readability instead of performance.

Comment: [kinda-related] http://i.qkme.me/35ksv1.jpg

Comment: As I understand in my case, both performance and readability number2 wins right?

Comment: I don't know about performance and frankly I don't care. Neither should you. :-) About readability: it depends whether you have a big HTML only (almost only) block whether you would go for the latter option. Most projects I'm currently working on only have small snippets of HTML so I let PHP handle it all. Just a matter of preference though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entering and exiting PHP, as opposed to echoing strings, has the advantage that a text editor can syntax highlight the HTML. If it's inside a PHP string, it cannot.

Performance-wise, I believe the difference to be completely insignificant and therefore irrelevant. This is a case of premature micro-optimization. Whichever method you choose, it is sure *not* to be the bottleneck in your application. If your application isn't performing adequately, then do profiling to identify what's actually taking too long.

Comment: All true but if you want to tell which of both is faster, it is the second one. You can do a benchmark to prove it.

Comment: Yes, initially I wrote with echo, but I didn't want to go crazy with \n to indent output properly, so I thought the other option for proper indentation. I like pretty output :=) And yes I'm a micro-OSD-optimizer type.

Comment: see generated opcode of these 2 instances,you guys would get the fact.i have to say,they're almost same,:-)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP compiler will probably parse both to pretty much the same with not a significant performance difference.
In general the way you output in PHP isn't a major performance concern.

You'd probably save a lot more performance by putting `$e[0]` in it's own variable, optimizing some other parts of the logic or using `ob_start('gz_handler')` to compress the output for faster transmission.

That being said, why not use `microtime()` and iterate that particular code a few thousand times? When it comes to performance, measuring is always better than somebody's opinion (including mine). Even better, use XDebug or a real profiler to find out where the processing time is being spend.